# Разобрать запись регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется запись в базе данных, хранящая в себе 2 значения - "introtext" и "fulltext", соответственно, предварительный и полный тексты статьи. Запись выглядит следующим образом:

```
::cck::85::/cck::
::introtext::Некоторый текст::/introtext::
::fulltext::Еще некоторый текст::/fulltext::
```

Как можно разобрать эту запись с помощью регулярных выражений? Необходимо выделить в переменную то, что внутри "fulltext".

Comment: не лучше будет хранить полный текст статьи и при необходимости резать его до определенного кол-ва знаков или вы используете описание которое отличается от текста статьи?

Comment: Да, описание статьи настраивается отдельно и может отличаться. В общем, такая структура предложена компонентом, который я использую, и я могу лишь взять эту строку из базы данных и разобрать ее, но не поменять структуру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
preg_match('/(?<=::fulltext::)(.*)(?=::\/fulltext::)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: А как можно изменить это выражение, чтобы строка разбивалась на массив параметров? То есть, считывать не только `fulltext`, но и остальные параметры, если встретятся в строке. Если вместо `::fulltext::` поставить `(.*)`, то работать не хочет.

Comment: @nup, `preg_match_all('/::[a-z]+::(.*)::\/[a-z]+::/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: Почему-то работает только в том случае, если параметры записаны в несколько строк. Если все одной строкой, то не работает.

Comment: @nup,  `preg_match_all('/:{2}[a-z]+:{2}(.*?):{2}\/[a-z]+:{2}/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);`

Answer (score 6):

Используйте шаблон:

```
preg_match("#::fulltext::(.*?)::/fulltext::#i", $data, $matches);
```